# For a maximal subgroup $H$ and $x \not\in H$, prove that $G = \langle H, x\rangle$

Tags: group-theory

Let G be a group and H a maximal subgroup of G,

I want to prove that if $x \not\in H$, then $G =  \langle H, x\rangle$. I could easily answer in the case G finite, but in general I don't really know what to do ....

Comment: What definition of "maximal" are you using? Doesn't this follow by the definition of maximal?

Comment: A maximal subgroup H of a group G is a proper subgroup, such that no proper subgroup K contains H strictly.

Comment: So is $\langle H,x\rangle$ a subgroup of $G$ containing $H$? Does it contain $H$ strictly?

Comment: Ooooooops ok I need to take a break. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions:

1. Is $\langle H,x\rangle$ a subgroup of $G$?
2. Is $H\subsetneq  \langle H, x\rangle$?

Answer (score 1):

So with the definition you just gave $\langle H,x\rangle$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that $H\subsetneq\langle H,x\rangle$ and because $H$ is maximal we have $\langle H,x\rangle=G$